# Error when insert iframe in joomla using K2 component

Tags: joomla1.7, joomla-k2

I am using `K2 component` for joomla 2.5, When I add a `iframe on a Item(or Article) in K2` is `Tiny MCE editor` show result, But when I run website in frontage is iframe not show ? How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You create a mod_wrapper and then enter data on that, set position="iframe"
2. In Item of K2 you using code {loadposition iframe}

Hope helpful